# Reading an Array in a DataFrame in R and calculating cosine distance

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file with three columns

```
sigID , author,lowered,array 
1, Lukic M,lukicm,"[ 0.05192188 -0.02984986 -0.01315994 -0.05446223  0.01090824 -0.0310401 -0.00134283 -0.0536921  -0.02986531 -0.01161558]"        
2, Houssin C,houssinc,"[ 0.05371874 -0.07439778  0.3917329  -0.15246899  0.35638699  0.14586256 0.12886068 -0.10721818 -0.14641574  0.08469024]"
....
```

How do I read this csv file in R?. (I am having parsing issue for array column)

How could i calculate the cosinesimilarity between array[1],array[2]

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you're missing a quotation mark (") at the end of line 1. Try running the code you've written so far after adding the quotation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to parse your array into vector:

```
myList <- strsplit(gsub("\\[\\s*|\\s*\\]", "", df$array), "\\s+")

myList
[[1]]
 [1] "0.05192188"  "-0.02984986" "-0.01315994" "-0.05446223" "0.01090824"  "-0.0310401"  "-0.00134283" "-0.0536921" 
 [9] "-0.02986531" "-0.01161558"

[[2]]
 [1] "0.05371874"  "-0.07439778" "0.3917329"   "-0.15246899" "0.35638699"  "0.14586256"  "0.12886068"  "-0.10721818"
 [9] "-0.14641574" "0.08469024"
```

Convert them to numeric before calculating the cosine distance:

```
mat <- do.call(cbind, lapply(myList, as.numeric))
mat
             [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]  0.05192188  0.05371874
 [2,] -0.02984986 -0.07439778
 [3,] -0.01315994  0.39173290
 [4,] -0.05446223 -0.15246899
 [5,]  0.01090824  0.35638699
 [6,] -0.03104010  0.14586256
 [7,] -0.00134283  0.12886068
 [8,] -0.05369210 -0.10721818
 [9,] -0.02986531 -0.14641574
[10,] -0.01161558  0.08469024
```

You can use `cosine` function from `lsa` package to calculate the cosine similarity:

```
library(lsa)
cosine(mat)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.2438864
[2,] 0.2438864 1.0000000
```

So the cosine similarity measure between vector 1 and vector 2 is 0.244.

**Note**: As to why you can't read the file, I guess you have one quote missing at the end of your first array. Otherwise, can't think of any reason why you can't read it. It is a normal `.csv` file.